# Polish Notation in C++

Tags: c++, math-expression-eval

This is my ***homemade*** Polish Notation implementation in C++.

I need a review for it to improve it and improve my coding skill. I also will put this implementation on my GitHub account

```
//======================================================
// Author      : Omar_Hafez
// Created     : 28 July 2022 (Thursday)  6:10:44 AM
//======================================================

#include <math.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

class PolishNotation {
   private:
        std::string operations[5] = {"+", "-", "*", "/", "^"};
        bool isDigit(char &ch) const { return ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'; }

        bool isOperation(std::string str) const {
            for (std::string x : operations) {
                if (str == x) return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        bool isNumber(std::string str) const {
            bool floatingPoint = 0;
            if (str.length() == 1) {
                return isDigit(str[0]);
            }
            for (int i = (str[0] == '-'); i < str.length(); i++) {
                if (!floatingPoint && str[i] == '.') {
                    floatingPoint = 1;
                    continue;
                }
                if (!isDigit(str[i])) return 0;
            }
            return 1;
        }

        bool isHigher(std::string a, std::string b) const {
            int cnt1 = 0, cnt2 = 0;
            cnt1 = (a == "+" || a == "-" ? 1 : a == "*" || a == "/" ? 2 : 3);
            cnt2 = (b == "+" || b == "-" ? 1 : b == "*" || b == "/" ? 2 : 3);
            return cnt1 > cnt2;
        }

        std::string calculate(std::string a, std::string b, std::string operation) const {
            long double x = stold(a);
            long double y = stold(b);
            if (operation == "+") return std::to_string(x + y);
            if (operation == "-") return std::to_string(x - y);
            if (operation == "*") return std::to_string(x * y);
            if (operation == "/") return std::to_string(x / y);
            if (operation == "^") return std::to_string(pow(x, y));
            return a;
        }

        std::vector<std::string> cutter(std::string str) const {
            std::vector<std::string> ope;
            std::string tmp = "";
            int ind = 0;

            while (ind < str.length()) {
                while (ind < str.length() &&
                       (isDigit(str[ind]) || str[ind] == '.')) {
                    tmp += str[ind++];
                }

                if (tmp != "") {
                    ope.push_back(tmp);
                    tmp = "";
                }

                while (ind < str.length() && !isDigit(str[ind])) {
                    tmp += str[ind++];
                }

                if (tmp.length() > 1 && tmp.back() == '-') {
                    tmp.pop_back();
                    ope.back() = "-" + ope.back();
                }

                if (tmp != "") {
                    ope.push_back(tmp);
                    tmp = "";
                }
            }
            return ope;
        }

        std::vector<std::string> convertToPolishNotation(std::vector<std::string> ope) const {
            if (ope.size() == 1) return {ope[0]};
            std::vector<std::string> a;
            a.push_back(ope[0]);
            std::stack<std::string> st;
            for (int i = 1; i < ope.size(); i += 2) {
                if (st.empty()) {
                    st.push(ope[i]);
                } else {
                    while (!st.empty() && !isHigher(ope[i], st.top())) {
                        a.push_back(st.top());
                        st.pop();
                    }
                    st.push(ope[i]);
                }
                a.push_back(ope[i + 1]);
            }
            while (!st.empty()) {
                a.push_back(st.top());
                st.pop();
            }
            return a;
        }

   public:
        std::vector<std::string> convertToPolishNotation(std::string str) const {
            return convertToPolishNotation(cutter(str));
        }

        long double calculateThePolishNotation(std::vector<std::string> a) const {
            int ind = 0;
            std::stack<std::string> st;
            while (ind < a.size()) {
                while (st.empty() || isNumber(st.top())) {
                    st.push(a[ind++]);
                }
                std::string operation = st.top();
                st.pop();
                std::string x = st.top();
                st.pop();
                std::string y = st.top();
                st.pop();
                st.push(calculate(y, x, operation));
            }
            return stold(st.top());
        }
};

int main() {
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;

    PolishNotation p = PolishNotation();
    std::cout << std::fixed << p.calculateThePolishNotation(p.convertToPolishNotation(str));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Include All Necessary Include Files

The code does not contain the necessary include for `std::string`, it does not compile on my computer (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019 Professional) without this.

## Don't Reinvent the Wheel

The C programming language has `ctype.h` which includes the function [isdigit()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) there is no need to write your own, you can include `cctype` to get access this function. You might also want to try the first answer in [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654636/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number-with-c).

## Alternate Implementation of the `calculate()` Function

One problem with the current implementation of the `calculate()` function is that there is no error checking, what happens if someone inputs an operator that you don't check for such as `%`, `^` or `$`.

A second problem with this function is that it is difficult to add a new operator/operation.

An alternate implementation that could solve both these problems would be to use `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` that uses a character or string as a Key and has a pointer to a function as the mapped return type.